# Reusar la subconsulta como tabla dos veces

Tags: mysql, subconsultas

Tratando de resolver el problema de hacker rank denominado [earnings of employees](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem?isFullScreen=true) obtengo resultados incorrectos con mi consulta, alguien sabe que puedo cambiar para corregir mi respuesta?

### enunciado

Definimos los ingresos totales de un empleado como su salario x mes trabajado, y las ganancias maximas totales como las ganacias maximas totales para cada empleado de la tabla Employee.
Escriba una consulta para hallar las ganacias maximas totales para todos los empleados, asi como el numero total de empleados que tienen las ganancias maximas totales. Luego imprima esos valores como enteros separados por espacios.

### Esquema de Tabla

[image: esquema]

### Datos de entrada

[image: datos de entrada]

### Resultado esperado

> 69952 1

### Explicacion del resultado esperado

[image: grafico de explicacion]
como se puede ver, el maximo salario ganado por un empleado es 69952. El unico empleado con esa ganancia es Kimberly.

### intentos actuales

```
select distinct * from
(SELECT
  max(employee_salary.total_earnings) as "maximum_total_earnings"
FROM
  (SELECT
    e.employee_id as "id"
    ,e.name
    ,(e.salary * e.months) as "total_earnings"
  FROM
    employee e) employee_salary) one
,
(SELECT
  count(id)
FROM
  (SELECT
    e.employee_id as "id"
    ,(e.salary * e.months) as "total_earnings"
  FROM
    employee e) employee_salary
WHERE employee_salary.total_earnings = (
  SELECT max(employee_salary.total_earnings)
)
GROUP BY id
) two;
```

### Salida actual

> 108064 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En MySQL 8 se puede usar una *Expresión de Tabla Común* para:

1. Obtener el ingreso total.
2. Agrupar -y ordenar- por ingreso total.

```
WITH incomes AS(
  SELECT employee_id
       , months*salary total_income
    FROM employees
)
SELECT total_income, count(1)
  FROM incomes
  GROUP BY total_income
  ORDER BY total_income DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Si no se tiene MySQL 8, una alternativa es:

```
SELECT months*salary total_income
     , count(1)
  FROM employees
    JOIN ( SELECT max(months*salary) max_income
             FROM employees
         ) mi
      ON months*salary = mi.max_income    
  GROUP BY total_income
```

Comment: excelente, con la observacion de que la tabla se llama employee y no employees :)